# Does anyone know if an asp.net page can be opened in an asp classic frame?

Tags: asp.net, asp-classic, window, frame

I am trying to find the way to accomplish the next thing:

I have an asp classic page with frames and from it I am opening some other pages which are opened inside frames of the first page. One of this pages opens an asp.net page. I wonder if is any way to open this asp.net page inside a frame of the first asp classic page mentioned. I am trying to achieve this, but I don't know even if it is possible or not.

Comment: If the ASP.NET page is already available, it sounds like you should just give it a try and see what happens.  The output from the server is just HTML, so I don't see why it should matter whether it's ASP.NET, asp "classic", php, or anything else generating the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this, because the browser renders the page inside the iframe, it has nothing relative to the server technology. You can even put a third party website page inside the iframe, no matter which technology was used in the server.